# implement: a string-to-string database

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures, nosql, storage

Just like `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>` but all data should be stored **on-disk** instead of in memory.

As I understand it, two parts should be done: indexing and storage. I've learned some data structures about indexing, like Linear-Hash or B-Tree, and writing an on-disk int->int database is not too hard. The problem is storage.

For integers, all records are in same size. once we get position to record by indexing, we can extract, modify or lazy-delete easily. but for strings, records are in flexible size. it should have (at least) the following problems:

1. put() a longer string: we cannot simply overwrite the old record, we dave to do del() and put() and the space for old record is wasted.
2. del(): the space for old record is wasted, too, and cannot be used again. (maybe we can collect deleted space with a garbage collector, but it costs extra space and makes fragment)
3. for int->int database, wasting spaces for several integers is not a big problem. but a string is longer, it costs more wasted spaces.

I need some advice/hints for solving the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take as an example how file systems manage variable-sized files.

They allocate file space in fixed-size chunks of about several kilobytes each and they link those chunks together to form entire files of arbitrary lengths.

If you need to grow your file, you allocate and link more chunks. If you need to shrink or delete it, you unlink and free one or more chunks.

About the only noticeable fragmentation here is internal, the wasted space in the last chunk of every file.

If you implement this using files, where each chunk is either a part of a potentially large file or is a file of its own, you don't need to delete/free it immediately. You can mark it in your control/meta data as free and then reuse later. You can implement compaction (removal of all free chunks) as a separate operation to be performed infrequently.

Comment: I think it is a little different from file-system. strings in database can be as small as several bytes. big chunks will waste too much space, and small chunks will increase IO times.

Comment: You can have chunks of several different sizes too and as your string grows or shrinks move it to the appropriately sized chunk.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a  mapper first. Whenever you get new strings, store them sequentially in a file, and store their locations on the  map.

Comment: Implement one with append() and lookup() is not difficult. The problem is how to modify/delete a record.

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like the definition of a key/value store. You can use really any system you like. From Oracle's Berkeley DB to Cassandra or Riak.

Comment: I want to implement one myself:)